Where can I find the Automattic\WooCommerce directory in my Wordpress files?
I am trying to find the Automattic\Woocommerce diretory in my wordpress files just to inspect some folders and files but can't find it. This is for the reason that this directory seems to be mostly used by php files in wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes
a php file in the mentioned directory
I;ve trying browsing through the directory but can't find it.
